# How do I connect a second controller to Minecraft Dungeons?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch, minecraft-dungeons

I have Minecraft Dungeons for Nintendo Switch, and I'm trying to add my second joy-con on Switch for local co-op.  The console recognizes both as connected, and other local multiplayer games like Mario Kart work fine, but I can't figure out how to add the 2nd controller to Dungeons:

[image]

The screen says "press (something) to join", but no button on the 2nd controller triggers any reaction.  From videos on YouTube etc, it looks like usually it says press L/R to join, but there's no indication of what to press on my screen.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the game is asking you to click on the stick (which is considered a different button in itself).

It should allow the second player to join.

Comment: Yes, I've tried moving the stick as well, doesn't work :/

Comment: Did you specifically try clicking (like pressing the stick toward the controller) ? You should hear a little click. If you are familiar with Sony, they call that R3 and L3.

Comment: OMG that was it!  Can't believe it was so simple, thank you!

Comment: Your welcome ! ^^ FYI, this input can be used in lots of games, especially if you are playing with the Joycon sideway. It might even be used in Dungeons to lock a target or something like that.